# nginx rewrite exclude url containing string

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to remove pagination from all URL's except ones that contain /page/[0-9]

example

Remove pagination:

```
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/2/
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/3/
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/4/
```

These would be redirected to

```
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/
https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/
```

We are currently using:

```
rewrite ^(.*/)[0-9]+/?$ $1 permanent;
```

which works good, but we want to exclude the redirect if the URL contains page like so:

```
https://www.example.com/page/2/?s=somesearch
https://www.example.com/page/3/?s=somesearch
https://www.example.com/page/4/?s=addition
```

Tried several attempts like:

```
rewrite ^(.*/)(?!page/[0-9]+)[0-9]+/?$ $1 permanent;
```

Will I need to use 'if' here with a location block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don‘t know whether nginx supports negative lookaheads, so I would suggest using something like:

```
rewrite  ^(/([^p]|p([^a]|a([^g]|g([^e]|e[^/])))).*/)[0-9]+/?$ $1 permanent;
```

which basically matches every „paginated“-request (like in your examples) not starting with `page/`

Comment: Seems like a good idea, it doesn't work though :(  Example URL:

https://www.example.com/some/thing/here/2/ this does not redirect, the 2 stays

Comment: Sorry, there was one pair of brackets missing. I corrected my answer, which should work now.

Comment: So it works by removing the pagination but its also removing it from URL's containg page, example https://www.example.com/page/2/?s=math

Comment: Sorry again - forgot a slash at the beginning of a line, which of course also belongs to a request. I corrected my answer again. Maybe I should test the things I suggest first (what I did now) before posting...